# Contador casos COVID y Angina no funciona

Tags: javascript

Necesito ayuda para que el código me diga `false` cuando no haya suficientes síntomas y `true` cuando los haya.

Algo me esta fallando, ya que en este momento solo puedo detectar por ejemplo, casos negativos pero no positivos de COVID, y viceversa:

consigna:

```
// ----- Closures -----

// EJERCICIO 10
// Implementar la función closureDetect que recibe como parámetro:
//  - Un array (symptoms) que va a contener en cada posición un string representando un
//    síntoma médico de alguna enfermedad
//  - Un número (min) que va a indicar la cantidad mínima de síntomas que debe tener un
//    paciente para considerar que posee la enfermedad
// Ejemplos:
//   var symptoms = ['fever', 'dry cough', 'tiredness', 'sore throat', 'diarrhoea', 'loss of taste', 'loss of smell'];
//   var covidDetector = closureDetect(symptoms, 3);
//
//   var personOne = {
//     name: 'Franco',
//     age: 26,
//     symptoms: ['fever', 'congestion', 'loss of taste', 'tiredness']
//   }
//
//   var personTwo = {
//     name: 'Toni',
//     age: 30,
//     symptoms: ['congestion', 'tiredness']
//   }
//
//   covidDetector(personOne); --> true
//   covidDetector(personTwo); --> false
//  [Observar los tests para otros casos]

function closureDetect(symptoms, min) {
  // Tu código aca:
```

Como se puede ver solo pasan 2/4, no se como modificar el contador para que quede bien

```
function closureDetect(symptoms, min) {
  // Tu código aca:
  var ContadorCovid = 0;
 var ContadorAngina = 0;
 var minCovid = min
 var minAngina = min
 return function () {

  if(symptoms.includes('fever')){
    ContadorCovid++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('dry cough')){
    ContadorCovid++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('tiredness cough')){
    ContadorCovid++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('sore throat')){
    ContadorCovid++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('diarrhoe')){
    ContadorCovid++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('loss of taste')){
    ContadorCovid++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('loss of smell')){
    ContadorCovid++;
      }
      if (ContadorCovid <= minCovid){
        return true;
      }
      if (ContadorCovid > minCovid){
        return false;
      }

  if(symptoms.includes('heaviness in chest')){
    ContadorAngina ++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('shortness of breath')){
    ContadorAngina ++;
  }
  if(symptoms.includes('nausea')){
    ContadorAngina ++;
  }
  if (ContadorAngina <= minAngina){
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Porque no haces dos funciones?  Una para cada enfermedad

Comment: Cuando ejecutas `return` el resto del codigo no se ejecuta, si quieres regresar los dos resultados, quizas sea mejor retornar un array

Comment: @JuanmaVergara bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar tu primer medalla.

Comment: Por favor, no borres una pregunta que ya ha sido bien recibida y que puede ayudar a futuros programadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes varios errores.

Si prestas atención al enunciado, vas a ver que:

- La función `closureDetect` sirve para crear una función que permite detectar cualquier enfermedad dandote los sintomas y el minimo para que de positivo
- Luego, con al función para testar creada, tenemos que usarla para ver cada una de las personas y sus sintomas individualmente.

#### Solución:

```js
function closureDetect(symptoms, min) {
  return function(persona) {
    let contador = 0;
    // Recorremos el arreglo de sintomas de la persona
    for (let i = 0; i < persona.symptoms.length; i++) {
    
      // Si el sintoma esta en los establecidos
      if (symptoms.includes(persona.symptoms[i])) contador++;

      // Si alcanzamos el minimo, dejamos de buscar
      if (contador >= min) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

//////////////
// TESTS
var symptoms = ['fever', 'dry cough', 'tiredness', 'sore throat', 'diarrhoea', 'loss of taste', 'loss of smell'];
var covidDetector = closureDetect(symptoms, 3);
var personOne = {
  name: 'Franco',
  age: 26,
  symptoms: ['fever', 'congestion', 'loss of taste', 'tiredness']
}

var personTwo = {
  name: 'Toni',
  age: 30,
  symptoms: ['congestion', 'tiredness']
}
console.log(covidDetector(personOne));
console.log(covidDetector(personTwo));
```

Comment: el `return function()` es un poco extraño, ya en el código original, y me parece que es `>= min`

Comment: con ese ejemplo que vos me diste solo me detecta los positivos pero no los negativos de ambas enfermedades, no se que esta mal

Comment: @Emeeus, el `return function` es para crear un `closure` (_seguramente es un ejercicio para aprender sobre estos_). Respecto al `>=` si, me parece que tenes razón.

Comment: @Marcos no tengo link, por donde te lo podria pasar al ejercicio?

Comment: @Marcos ahi lo edite

Comment: dale muchas gracias

Comment: @Marcos perfecto, gracias por los comentarios, con eso pude terminar de entender el problema y ahora me quedo bastante claro

Answer (score 0):

Basado en la respuesta de otro compañero, yo lo haria asi:

```js
function closureDetect(symptoms, min) {
  // Tu código aca:
  var ContadorCovid = 0;
  var ContadorAngina = 0;
  var covid = false;
  var angina = false;
  return function() {

    if (symptoms.includes('fever')) ContadorCovid++;
    if (symptoms.includes('dry cough')) ContadorCovid++;
    if (symptoms.includes('tiredness cough')) ContadorCovid++;
    if (symptoms.includes('sore throat')) ContadorCovid++;
    if (symptoms.includes('diarrhoe')) ContadorCovid++;
    if (symptoms.includes('loss of taste')) ContadorCovid++;
    if (symptoms.includes('loss of smell')) ContadorCovid++;
    //
    if (symptoms.includes('heaviness in chest')) ContadorAngina++;
    if (symptoms.includes('shortness of breath')) ContadorAngina++;
    if (symptoms.includes('nausea')) ContadorAngina++;
    //
    if (ContadorCovid >= min) covid = true;
    if (ContadorAngina >= min) angina = true;
    return [covid, angina];
  }
}
var test = closureDetect(['fever'],1);
console.log(test());
```